How to understand how StackTraceElement works?
I'm very new to programming. I try to learn from Code Gym. But I still don't understand some things. For example, why is it crucial to put StackTraceElement[]... in last method on the chain in order for it to print all the methods that were used in that "chain". Why can't I start use this code in the main method like in second block of code. Sorry if it sounds stupid I just don't get it.
public class ExceptionPrzyklad
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    method1();
  }

  public static void method1()
  {
    method2();
  }

  public static void method2()
  {
    method3();
  }

  public static void method3()
  {
     StackTraceElement[] stackTraceELement = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement element : stackTraceELement)
    {
       System.out.println(element.getMethodName());
    }
  }
}

public class ExceptionPrzyklad
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceELement = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement element : stackTraceELement)
    {
       System.out.println(element.getMethodName());
    }

    method1();
  }

  public static void method1()
  {
    method2();
  }

  public static void method2()
  {
    method3();
  }

  public static void method3()
  {
    
  }
}


Because the stack gets populated at runtime. If you checked the stack trace in main how would the runtime know what will happen in the method chain? How would it know, for example, that method1 will absolutely for sure call method2 and the JVM will not crash before it gets called?

getStackTrace() returns the actual stack, in second code example the methods were not yet executed so these are not on the stack (a StackTraceElement  is added to the current stack when a/each method is called, and removed after returning from that method call)

Why should the stack trace created in your second example contain method1()? Your main method is calling a lot of methods, currentThread(), getStackTrace(), getMethodName(), println(…), and method1(). Why should the stack trace contain method1() and not one of the other methods? There’s an answer to the question “Where am I?” without ambiguity, but not to questions like “Where have I been?” or “Where will I be?”

Lovely Lovely people, thanks for Your help. I think i finally understand but it didn't come easy. Correct me if Im wrong, but does stackTraceELement object "reads" all the methods that have been used up to this moment? So that's why when I use it in main method it just simply reads only this method, cause all other methods haven't been started yet? At first it wasn't obvious for me as I thought main method "knows" everything that is going on in program from the beginning to the end of working program.

StackTrace Definition:

A stack trace is a report of the active stack frames at a "specific
point in time during the execution of a program". It's also known as a
"stack backtrace" or "stack traceback".

So since it does TraceBack,it holds info about all the locations traced up to the Destination i.e where you've called ".getStackTrace()" function,
in the first Scenario Above it was called in method3 so it'll contain Trace of all Locations(Source:main) up to method3

main->method1->method2->method3

in Second Scenario above where it's called in Main function only prints the Trace of main function

main

I Shared info as of my knowledge and would be great if someone notify me where If i'm wrong.
